# How to read a text file (dictionary) in a thread-friendly way

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, dictionary

I'm in a computer science class and we have been charged with making a hash table in C and populating it from a dictionary.txt file. A friend of mine and I are a little competitive with grades / performance of our programs, so we asked if we could use threads. 100% new to threads, but I know enough to implement one and to watch out for race conditions.

My issue is that I want to read the file in as fast as possible, which means threads. I'm having trouble deciding how to split it into thread-friendly chunks without damaging integrity of the file.

I can't just break it up into bytes, because all we know is that the strings in the dictionary are no larger than 50 characters.

My only current thought is to have 2 threads, one at the start and one at the finish to read from opposite ends and every time they hit a newline they hash it into my table. Obviously the one starting from the end would need to flip the string, first.

We're compiling with gcc on a linux server, if that helps at all.

Comment: I/O bandwidth is much more likely to be your bottleneck, rather than CPU.

Comment: Have one main thread that goes through the file and then sends the chunks to be hashed to the child threads, for example. It will only help in the case when hashing is very expensive, otherwise not worth the trouble.

Comment: If you're wondering "how can I optimize my program?", [Numbers Every Programmer Should Know](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~rcs/research/interactive_latency.html) is a great place to start.

Comment: And [here's a basic HTML version](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/volante/important_numbers.html) of that list, by popular demand :)

Answer (score 3):

Threads are not suitable for this kind of problem. They might even slow down the performance because of the synchronization code that you will have to use. You will get better performance if you minimize the read operations. For example you can read the entire dictionary in memory with a single read and then process it in memory.

```
FILE *f= fopen("/usr/share/dict/linux.words","r");

// find the file size
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
int size = ftell(f);
rewind(f);

// Allocate buffer and read the entire file in a single read.
char buff[size];
if (f) {
    int len = fread(buff, 1, size, f);
    buff[len]='\0';
    fclose(f);
}

// Process the file (assuming entries are separated by newlines)
char *token  = strtok(buff, "\n");
for (; token; token = strtok(NULL, "\n"))
    printf ("%s\n", token);
```

I have used a single fread in the code above for simplicity, however to be fail safe you will have to put the fread call in a loop because it is not guaranteed that the OS will return all bytes in a single call.

```
int lastlen=0;
int len;
while((len = fread(buff+lastlen, 1, size-lastlen-1, f)) > 0) {
    lastlen+=len;
}
```